# extra module name symbol in shared library with clang

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, c++20, c++-modules

I am creating a simple shared library with clang on Arch Linux using clang-git 16.0.0 builded from source. The library name is libsum and it provides function to make a sum of two integers.

```cpp
// liba.cc
export module liba;
namespace space {
    export int sum(int a, int b) { return a + b; }
}
```

```cpp
// liba.h
namespace space {
    int sum(int,int);
}
```

Library builds without errors

```
clang++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -fprebuilt-module-path=. --precompile -x c++-module -fimplicit-modules -fimplicit-module-maps -fPIC liba.cc
clang++ -c liba.pcm -o liba.o
clang++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libsum.so -o libsum.so liba.o
```

When I tried to use it like this

```cpp
#include <liba.h>
int main() { return space::sum(1, 2); }
// ./main || echo $?
```

using

```
clang++ -I. -c main.cc 
clang++ main.o -o main -Wl,-rpath,. -L. -lsum
```

linker returns undefined reference to `space::sum(int, int)`.
So I've checked the library

```
$ nm -D libsum.so | grep sum
00000000000010f0 T _ZN5spaceW4liba3sumEii
```

Function contains extra module name therefore I can't reach it.
On my other system with clang 14.0.6 library builds successfully and provides a valid name

```
$ nm -D libsum.so | grep sum
00000000000010f0 T _ZN5space3sumEii
```

and I can use it. I've tried multiple packages with clang 15 and clang 16 but had the same issue. I've tried to use `-fuse-ld=lld` at linking with corresponded `lld` version but it does not help.

How to avoid the problem with extra `liba` name in library and access the function? Please give some advice on what can be broken and what I can miss at building/installing clang (llvm) package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare a name in the purview of a module is to declare that this module *owns* that name. When a name is declared outside of the purview of a module, that name is *not* owned by a module.

These represent distinct sets of names, a kind of namespace outside of namespaces. That is, a name that is not declared in a module represents a different entity from any name declared in the purview of a module, even if the literal text of those names are the same. As such, modules are part of name mangling, just like namespaces.

So your main file includes a header that declares the name `space::sum`. This declaration is not in the purview of a module, so the name will be looked up in the set of names not in a module. But your library compilation declared the name `space::sum` as part of a module, and that is now baked into the library. Thus, when your main file goes looking for `space::sum`, it cannot find it, because the only `space::sum` in the compiled library is one that is part of a module.

If you put something in a module, the standard thinks you're *serious* about that. You can design a library that can be built as a module or not as a module. But these processes will produce *different library* files. So if you build a library to be consumed as a module, you have to consume it as a module.

Comment: I want to use my library as module. I separated function declaration and definition. I created `liba.cppm` for function prototype with two lines: `export module liba;` and `namespace space { export int sum(int,int); }`. Then I removed `export` from first line in `liba.cc` and produced object file which was used at shared library creation. I compiled my `main.cc` which contains `import liba;` using `-fprebuilt-module-path=.` to grab `liba.pcm`. It works fine with clang 14 but still not working with 16. `nm` outputs for libraries are same as in the question. Can you point out what I'm missing?

Comment: @Serg: I can't really follow the textual equivalent of a diff like that. If you're having some other problem, you'll have to ask a new question, with all of the code and build stuff provided. As well as the compiler version.

Comment: There is no need for a new question. Your primary answer contains all the details. Since function `sum` declared as a part of a module I have to add information about the module to the library using `pcm` file. In order to do this I just add it to the file list at the library creation step: `clang++ -shared -Wl,-soname,libsum.so -o libsum.so liba.o liba.pcm`. Now when I import module in `main.cc` with `import liba;` the function is available. This solves the problem.